# Altering server role on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a SQL Server user and link it to my database, so I used the following script

```
-- Create the user 'tester' for database PILLS
USE [master]

DROP DATABASE [PILLS]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [PILLS]
GO

-- CREAZIONE UTENTE
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT sp.name AS ServerLoginName, dp.name AS DBUserName FROM sys.server_principals sp LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON sp.sid = dp.sid WHERE sp.name = 'tester')
    CREATE LOGIN [tester] WITH PASSWORD=N'tester', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[PILLS], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

-- MAPPING UTENTE SU DATABASE
USE [PILLS]
CREATE USER tester FROM LOGIN tester;

-- CAMBIO ACCESSI
USE [PILLS]

ALTER LOGIN [tester] DISABLE
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [securityadmin] ADD MEMBER [tester]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [serveradmin] ADD MEMBER [tester]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [setupadmin] ADD MEMBER [tester]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [processadmin] ADD MEMBER [tester]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [diskadmin] ADD MEMBER [tester]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [tester]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [bulkadmin] ADD MEMBER [tester]
GO

ALTER LOGIN [tester] ENABLE
GO
```

The script runs fine but my user doesn't have the server roles as I set previously.
Each instruction looks fine and I've also compared them with the ones generated by SQL Server.
Any ideas?

Comment: `USER` <> `LOGIN`. You can't assign server roles to a `USER`; they are assigned to the `LOGIN`.

Comment: How are you determining the login does not have the server roles?

Comment: Have you executed the query at [To view role membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-server-role-transact-sql#g-to-view-role-membership) to confirm that your new login does not have those roles?

Comment: @DanGuzman I checked with Management Studio

Comment: @Johnny88, where in SSMS? Did you view the server role memberships for the tester login in SSMS object explorer?